# Subclass NSProgressIndicator

Tags: macos, cocoa, subclass, nsprogressindicator

i like to subclass a NSProgressIndicator. I've used this code and i set the Subclass in the Interface Builder:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
NSRect rect = NSInsetRect([self bounds], 1.0, 1.0);
CGFloat radius = rect.size.height / 2;
NSBezierPath *bz = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect xRadius:radius yRadius:radius];
[bz setLineWidth:2.0];
[[NSColor blackColor] set];
[bz stroke];

rect = NSInsetRect(rect, 2.0, 2.0);
radius = rect.size.height / 2;
bz = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect xRadius:radius yRadius:radius];
[bz setLineWidth:1.0];
[bz addClip];
rect.size.width = floor(rect.size.width * ([self doubleValue] / [self maxValue]));
NSRectFill(rect);
```

When the app starts its looks like this:
[image: App start]

But during the copy progress the old bar shows up.
[image: During copying]

Whats wrong?

Comment: You forgot to add [super drawRect:rect]

Comment: It's doesn't work with [super drawRect:rect].

Comment: So i add NSLog to my subclass and the subclass calls only once at start but during the copy progress the class is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the progress bar's progress is not drawn in `drawRect:`, so just overriding `drawRect:` is not enough. However, if you make the progress bar layer backed, you are responsible for doing all the drawing.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setWantsLayer%3a):

> The view class automatically creates a backing layer for you (using
>   `makeBackingLayer` if overridden), and you must use the view class’s
>   drawing mechanisms.

Check the "Core Animation Layer" in IB or add this to your sub class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yeah i forgot to set Core Animation Layer. Thx... sry new to Cocoa i never try to subclass before ;D

Answer (score 1):

I followed the above advice (thanks!), but unfortunately discovered that when the NSProgressIndicator was resized, it disappeared, but only on the first viewing (it was inside a drawer).

Rather than try and understand what was happening, I realised you don't actually need the old control, as what I was doing is very simple (a strength indicator that changes color). Just create a subclass of NSView.

So this is it:

```
@interface SSStrengthIndicator : NSView
/// Set the indicator based upon a score from 0..4
@property (nonatomic) double strengthScore;
@end

@implementation SSStrengthIndicator
- (void)setStrengthScore:(double)strength
{
    if (_strengthScore != strength) {
        _strengthScore = strength;
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
   }
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSRect rect = NSInsetRect([self bounds], 1.0, 2.0);
    double  val = (_strengthScore + 1) * 20;
    if (val <= 40)
        [[NSColor redColor] set];
    else if (val <= 60)
        [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
    else
        [[NSColor greenColor] set];

    rect.size.width = floor(rect.size.width * (val / 100.0));
    [NSBezierPath fillRect:rect];
}
@end
```