# How to increase height of Yosemite NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac, nsprogressindicator

I am working on an application using Xamarin for Mac that will run on both Mavericks and Yosemite. I want the make the `NSProgressIndicator` bar height to be 20 pixels, but my attempts at subclassing it and overriding `DrawRect` haven't resulted in what I need.

How do I give the `NSProgressIndicator` a custom height? Can I draw the default just taller or do I need to implement [completely custom draw code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464814/subclass-nsprogressindicator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid to say that you're going to have to roll your own progress indicator if you want this kind flexibility.  On the other hand, I'd caution against making this kind of modification - creating slick user interfaces is hard, and if you're using your own custom UI widgets then your app may end up looking janky and un-mac-like.